# What are/is the difference(s) between SPRITE and PNG?

Tags: graphics, png, sprite

I searched the web but still confused that what are/is the difference(s) between sprite and png?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about image formats not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

A PNG (Portable Network Graphics) is a file format, famous for enabling transparent backgrounds because of it's Alpha channel.

The Sprite is a image used in design, the file format doesn't matter, but in most cases it's used as PNG or GIF, because of the transparent background.

You can use sprites to make a movement of a character in gaming, or a spritesheet full of images used in web design where you link the coordinates of the desired sprite.